# Java NIO Selectors- multiple Selectors

Tags: java, nio

The question is not about creating normal arrays. Kindly provide me with an example of how to create array of selectors in java nio.
The following code throws nullpointerexception

Selector [] selectors;
selectors[0] = Selector.open();

Comment: Is this about NIO selectors or CSS selectors.  They are completely different things!!

Comment: @StephenC The question is really: "How do I create an array." And the answer should be: "Use a List instead."

Comment: Well assuming that that is what the really question is ... I'm sure we can find one that this is a duplicate of.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I dont want to create a List. I want to create an **array of Java nio Selectors**.

Comment: @StephenC Hi Stephen.. Can u give me an example of how to create array of selectors in Java NIO.

Comment: `Selector[] selectors = new Selector[42];`  Then write a loop to initialize the array.  This is very basic Java stuff.  Try reading a Java tutorial.